# Is there still a place for SqlConnection.ClearPool(SqlConnection) in 2023?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, connection-pooling

I have some background services that run every hour looping over potentially 1000s of databases, where it's opening them and checking for data that requires action.

There are some performance issues that best as I can tell map back to calling `SqlConnection.ClearPool()`. This often seems to take about 0.45s during our busier hours.

Reading this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-connection-pooling?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Does it seem like in 2023 that this is no longer necessary (except for where database dropping is required), and that using statements are sufficient?

This is roughly how the code looks - any affirmation either way, or where to look around the performance of `SqlConnection.ClearPool` would be much appreciated

```
using (var masterContext = Context.CreateNew())
{
    var thousandsOfCompanies = GetActiveCompanies(masterContext).ToList();                    
                
    foreach (var company in thousandsOfCompanies )
    {
        try
        {                            
            using (var context = Helper.CreateForDatabase(company.ServerName, company.DatabaseName))
            {
                // Do things
                masterContext.SaveChanges();
                SqlConnection.ClearPool(context.SqlConnection);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            exception.Log();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd say it really depends on what you are doing within the scope of each DbContext, especially that outer one. I've never really had a need to try and dump SQL connections from the pool. In terms of performance tuning my advice is looking at what you really need to load and avoid tracking entities any longer than they absolutely benefit from being tracked. Performance issues over bulk quantities of data usually come from leaving large numbers of tracked entities in a DbContext instance over an extended period of operation.

Comment: I'd also say we don't know what's going on in GetActiveCompanies() and Helper.CreateForDatabase.  why do you keep the first context alive for so long?  I'd grab your list which I hope is only pulling back ServerName and DatabaseName and close the first connection.  Then it looks like you are just spinning up new contexts, which can  do with DbContextfactory.  Does CreateForDatabase just wrap that and create dynamic connection strings?  if you aren't re-using your connection, when you create your connection string, i'd just set pooling=false.

Comment: Thank you both, I was barking up the wrong tree and Steve nailed it. The slow downs were purely caused by a save changes call in the loop (edited code above), so checking 5000 entities for changes 5000 times.. Oops. Needless to say I'll be updating this to be paged and save once per page.